# How react-hook-form prevents rerender when formState is not declared

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm watching a react-hook-form tutorial. They show an example at https://youtu.be/RkXv4AXXC_4?t=170

```js
let renderCount = 0;

const App = () => {
  const {register, handleSubmit, /*formState: {errors}*/} = useForm();
  renderCount++;
  //...
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-magic-1-pcxdhh?file=/src/App.js

If you submit a form that has validation errors without declaring `formState: {errors}` above, the component won't rerender.

But if you declare `formState: {errors}` above, the component will rerender when you submit with errors.

What is the mechanism that is used to prevent rerender in the first case, and do it in the second case?

Comment: provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @LinDu provided code sandbox with minimal example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `formState` is a `Proxy`. If you access anything from it, it subscribes to that property and re-renders the component when that property changes its value

For example: If you access the `isValid` property, the component will re-render if:

- both inputs are empty, since they are required, isValid will be false
- both inputs have value, isValid will be true

Comment: I don't understand how does the Proxy understand that a property (errors) has been accessed?

Is this achieved using the "property getter method" in the `formState` object. And that destructuring of formState triggers the "property getter method" in a same way as if it has been accessed using the `formState.property`?

Comment: You are doing {formState: {errors}} = useForm(). It is same as const errors = useForm().formState.errors. You get errors from formState, this way you are subscribing to it. It is a getter, it returns the value to you and subscribes to changes

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling for two days because of this. I'm using shadcn-ui, and they used formState inside one of their components. This caused a complete rerender to the form everytime a validation error message gets updated.